# DisplayPromptAsync always displaying on main window

Tags: c#, popup, maui, multi-window

I'm studying to become a developer; as a formative project, I'm working on a desktop app to help me organize local amateur chess tournaments with MAUI. Basically, I want to be able to open multiple windows during the same execution, so that I can run various parallel tournaments on the same machine.
On the MainPage I placed a button that creates a new window that displays the NewTournamentPage

```
private void NewTournamentButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Current.OpenWindow(new Window()
        {
            Page = new NewTournamentPage()
        }) ;
    }
```

in the NewTournamentPage I placed a button to add a new player to the tournament, and I want the window to freeze until the user inserts the player name, but without blocking the execution of the other windows. DisplayPromptAsync seems to be exactly what I'm looking for, so I did this:

```
public async void AddNewPlayer_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string newPlayerName = await this.DisplayPromptAsync("Add new Player", "Name:");
    //code to add player to tournament
    ...
}
```

When I execute and click the NewTournamentButton multiple times, the windows are created with no problems, and they all work independently from each other, but when I press the AddNewPlayer button, the popup pops on the MainPage window, not on the one calling the method, and it takes and saves the input in newPlayerName; then, the same thing happens on all secondary windows, in order of creation, without updating newPlayerName. What is happening here? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is just the case as you said.  And I have created a new issue about this problem on github.

You can follow it up here: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7650.

Thanks for your feedback and support for maui very much.